# Hadoop distcp exception

Tags: hadoop, distcp

We are using dictcp to copy data from CDH4 to CDH5. When we run the command on CDH5 destination namenode, we get the following exception. Please let me know if you have already encountered the problem and know the solution. Thanks.

```
5/01/05 18:15:47 ERROR tools.DistCp: Exception encountered 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.lang.NoSuchMethodError): org.apache.hadoop.net.NetworkTopology.pseudoSortByDistance(Lorg/apache/hadoop/net/Node;[Lorg/apache/hadoop/net/Node;)V
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeManager.sortLocatedBlocks(DatanodeManager.java:354)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1618)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:482)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:322)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:587)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1026)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2013)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2009)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2007)

at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1411)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1364)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
at sun.proxy.$Proxy14.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:246)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
at sun.proxy.$Proxy15.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.callGetBlockLocations(DFSClient.java:1179)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:1169)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:1159)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.fetchLocatedBlocksAndGetLastBlockLength(DFSInputStream.java:270)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.openInfo(DFSInputStream.java:237)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.<init>(DFSInputStream.java:230)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.open(DFSClient.java:1457)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$3.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:301)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$3.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:297)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.open(DistributedFileSystem.java:297)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.openFile(SequenceFile.java:1832)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1752)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1773)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Sorter$SortPass.run(SequenceFile.java:2825)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Sorter.sortPass(SequenceFile.java:2785)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Sorter.sort(SequenceFile.java:2733)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Sorter.sort(SequenceFile.java:2774)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.util.DistCpUtils.sortListing(DistCpUtils.java:356)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.CopyListing.validateFinalListing(CopyListing.java:145)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.CopyListing.buildListing(CopyListing.java:91)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.GlobbedCopyListing.doBuildListing(GlobbedCopyListing.java:90)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.CopyListing.buildListing(CopyListing.java:84)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.createInputFileListing(DistCp.java:353)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.execute(DistCp.java:160)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.run(DistCp.java:121)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.main(DistCp.java:401)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is because of protocol mismatch between two clusters.

As Hadoop version used in the source and destinations are different, you cannot use distcp by using hdfs://Cluster2-Namenode1:Port/ in source or destination, you have to use webhdfs:// instead of simple hdfs as follows.

```
hadoop distcp /source-directory webhdfs://Cluster2-Namenode1:50070/dir/
```

Please note 50070 is the default namenode Web UI, If you have configured different port for HDFS namenode WebUI, modify 50070 to your modified port.

Comment: One more point. For using this, you have to enable webhdfs in the cluster